# how do I allow my app to access iphones contacts and store them for use in app

Tags: iphone, flash

Hey so I am making an app and was wondering how would I go about on being able to access the iPhone's contacts and click the phone numbers that you want and they will be stored for use.

UPDATED -----

I am dev in Adobe Flash CS5.5

Comment: Have you read the [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744)?

Comment: no had no idea...that will be handy!  But how would I make this work in flash?

Comment: Sorry - missed the Flash requirement when I posted. I have no clue about Flash. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include `AddressBook.framework` also i use `MContact` class for use of contact name,number,etc..

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/ABPerson.h>

[contactList removeAllObjects];

// open the default address book. 
ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
if (!m_addressbook) {
    NSLog(@"opening address book");
}

// can be cast to NSArray, toll-free
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);

// CFStrings can be cast to NSString!

for (int i=0;i < nPeople;i++) { 
 MContact *contact = [[MContact alloc] init];

 ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);
 CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
 firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
 lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
 contact.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

 ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
 if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) > 0) {
  contact.email =  (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0);
  [contactList addObject:contact];
 }

 CFRelease(ref);
 CFRelease(firstName);
 CFRelease(lastName);


}

////and here MContact is NObject (Bean) file bellow

@interface MContact : NSObject { 
NSString *email; 
NSString *name; 
NSString *lastName; 
NSString *phone; 

BOOL isSelected; 
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *email; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *phone; 

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSelected; 
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *displayName; 
@end
```

Comment: i dont know mate, i use this code for retrive and use contact data from iPhone in iPhone app.

Comment: No this is very easy, just see the flow of code.. you can easily use inbuilt AddressBook framework of iPhone SDK. so you can get whole contact data from your device .. so its easy to use in iPhone app but in Flash i dont know mate..